# Is there any reliable API to Get Windows Folder in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, api, directory

Is there any reliable API to Get Windows Folder in Windows in C++?
I am using the following way, however it failed.

```
    BOOL CQUserInfoHelper::GetWindowsPath(CString& strWindowsPath)
    {
        TCHAR windowsPathTemp[MAX_PATH];
        int nSize = MAX_PATH;
        ::GetWindowsDirectory(
            windowsPathTemp,
            nSize);
        strWindowsPath = windowsPathTemp;
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: "it failed" is not an error description I like to read.

Comment: It do not return XX:\\Windows, but something else. it is reported by my user, I can not debug it on their pc

Comment: there are 2 resonses fro that:

If the length is greater than the size of the buffer, the return value is the size of the buffer required to hold the path. 

If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError. 

handle those issues

Comment: You should also always initialize a string buffer to 0 e.g. TCHAR windowsPathTemp[MAX_PATH] = {0}

Comment: @humbagumba: Why? GetWindowsDirectory() uses it as an `[out]` parameter. Microsofts internal API check tools guarantee that an `[out]` paramenter is never read. If it's not read, its contents do not matter.

Comment: @MSalters - yes but if only a portion of that string buffer is 'filled' the remaining data may just be garbage.

Comment: @mrl33t: Any C or C++ programmer that reads past the first \0 will be unlikely to be deterred by a second \0, or a third. And since you can't fill every byte of memory with \0, I'll just settle for the one \0 provided by GetWindowsDirectory()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This -

```
const DWORD dwBufferLength = 65537;
CStringW strBuffer;

if (!::GetCurrentDirectory(   dwBufferLength , 
                              strBuffer.GetBuffer(dwBufferLength))    ) 
   return L"";
```

...

```
strBuffer.ReleaseBuffer();
```